# String builder with fixed length of characters and spaces in right side in C'

Tags: c#, padding, stringbuilder

I need string builder helps for following scenarion, I want to create DTA document so that,

```
var name = GetName() ---// Get the name from database Ex- "ABC Gmbh"

StringBuilder _header = new StringBuilder();
_header.Append(string.Format("{0,4}", "0128"));
_header.Append(string.Format("{0,20}", name ));
```

Output will be  "0128------------ABC Gmbh"

but i need a output like "0128ABC Gmbh-----------"

Note - "-" is refering a empty space. so i need the rest of spaces from right side, not left side

Comment: Use [`String.PadRight Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Also StringBuilder has an AppendFormat method...

Comment: using the PadRight you can give fix length of spaces. Here name is a variable that should change dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the way to do it,

var name = GetName() ---// Get the name from database Ex- "ABC Gmbh"

```
StringBuilder _header = new StringBuilder();
_header.Append(string.Format("{0,4}", "0128"));
_header.Append(string.Format("{0,-20}", name ));
```

string.Format("{0,-20}", "ABC Gmbh") will string allign left side and set the spaces to right
Padright is not the right way because in this scenario character length can be different each time

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `String.Format`:

```
_header.Append("128".PadLeft(4, '0'));
_header.Append("ABC Gmbh".PadRight(20, ' '));
```

Output: `"0128ABC Gmbh            "`

Comment: using the PadRight you can give fix length of spaces. Here name can be a variable that should change dynamically. so we cannot say how mach lengh of spaces each time

Comment: @Jayakaran: i don't understand, `PadRight(20, ' ')` means that it will add up to 20 spaces but only if the string has less characters. So if the string is already 19 characters long it will add only one space.